# MS Access Linked Table Manager full network path

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is there any way of inputting the full network path in MS Access Linked Table Manager?

[image]

Comment: What are you asking here? by full network path do you mean a UNC path (i.e. \\server\share\folder...\)? The examples you're showing are all in a locally saved database so don't have a network path.

Comment: @citizenkong thats correct the full network path, UNC path (i.e. \\server\share\folder...) , i've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your target network location is accessible via Windows Explorer, you should be able to choose it in the *Select New Location* dialog from the *Linked Table Manager*.

In the *Linked Table Manager*, place a checkmark next to a linked table, ensure the *"Always prompt for new location"* box is checked, and click *OK* to bring up the *Select New Location* dialog.  Then navigate to your network location and select the source database:

[image]

After clicking *Open* in that dialog, you should be returned to the *Linked Table Manager* and see that link has been updated with the UNC path:

[image]

If that approach doesn't work in your situation, I don't think the *Linked Table Manager* can do it.  In that case, you could use VBA code to modify the `.Connect` property of the linked table's `DAO.TableDef`

Comment: great thanks I'll check this out once I get back to working on the database , thanks again